# Problems about the kategori is not updating

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm having a problem updating the kategori only, the other can be updated just fine.

I want to change my kategori from Artikel Kucing to Coba kategori.

here is the console :
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGadO.jpg)

1. Number 1 is telling that the kategori is still default or its still kategori kucing
2. Number 2 is telling that I selected another kategori or a different one from the select button kategori and that is Coba Kategori.
3. Number 3 the kategori has changed to Coba Kategori but the update does not appear on the adminDashboard.

Here is my code:

AdminDashboard.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Box, Button, Paper, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { DataGrid, gridClasses } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import moment from "moment";
import axios from "axios";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const AdminDashboard = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.userProfile);
  const [selectedKategori, setSelectedKategori] = useState("");
  const [kategoriList, setKategoriList] = useState([]);

  // const untuk kategori
  const fetchKategoriList = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/kategori/show");
      setKategoriList(data.kategori);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchKategoriList();
  }, []);

  const displayPost = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/post/show");
      setPosts(data.posts);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    displayPost();
  }, []);

  //delete post by Id
  const deletePostById = async (e, id) => {
    // console.log(id)
    if (window.confirm("Apa anda yakin ingin menghapus?")) {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.delete(`/api/delete/post/${id}`);
        if (data.success === true) {
          toast.success(data.message);
          displayPost();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        toast.error(error);
      }
    }
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      field: "_id",
      headerName: "ID",
      width: 150,
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: "title",
      headerName: "Nama Judul",
      width: 150,
    },

    {
      field: "image",
      headerName: "Gambar",
      width: 150,
      renderCell: (params) => <img width="40%" src={params.row.image.url} />,
    },
    {
      field: "likes",
      headerName: "Suka",
      width: 150,
      renderCell: (params) => params.row.likes.length,
    },
    {
      field: "comments",
      headerName: "Komentar",
      width: 150,
      renderCell: (params) => params.row.comments.length,
    },
    {
      field: "postedBy",
      headerName: "Dibuat oleh",
      width: 150,
      valueGetter: (data) => data.row.postedBy.name,
    },
    {
      field: "createdAt",
      headerName: "Tanggal Input",
      width: 150,
      renderCell: (params) =>
        moment(params.row.createdAt).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"),
    },

    {
      field: "kategori",
      headerName: "Kategori",
      width: 150,
      valueGetter: (params) => {
        const selectedKategori = kategoriList.find(
          (kategori) => kategori._id == params.row.kategoriId
        );
        return selectedKategori ? selectedKategori.namakat : "N/A";
      },
    },

    {
      field: "Aksi",
      width: 100,
      renderCell: (value) => (
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            width: "170px",
          }}
        >
          <Link to={`/admin/post/edit/${value.row._id}`}>
            <IconButton aria-label="edit">
              <EditIcon sx={{ color: "#1976d2" }} />
            </IconButton>
          </Link>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="delete"
            onClick={(e) => deletePostById(e, value.row._id)}
          >
            <DeleteIcon sx={{ color: "red" }} />
          </IconButton>
        </Box>
      ),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Box>
      <h1>Halo Admin {user && user.name} !</h1>
      <Typography variant="h4" sx={{ color: "black", pb: 3 }}>
        Mengelola Kucing
      </Typography>
      <Box sx={{ pb: 2, display: "flex", justifyContent: "right" }}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="success" startIcon={<AddIcon />}>
          <Link
            style={{ color: "white", textDecoration: "none" }}
            to="/admin/post/create"
          >
            Tambah Data
          </Link>{" "}
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <Paper sx={{ bgcolor: "white" }}>
        <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
          <DataGrid
            getRowId={(row) => row._id}
            sx={{
              "& .MuiTablePagination-displayedRows": {
                color: "black",
              },
              color: "black",
              [`& .${gridClasses.row}`]: {
                bgcolor: "white",
              },
            }}
            rows={posts}
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={3}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[3]}
            checkboxSelection
          />
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default AdminDashboard;
```

EditPost.js

```
  Box,
  Button,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
} from "@mui/material";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";
import CloudUploadIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CloudUpload";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import { modules } from "../components/moduleToolbar";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const validationSchema = yup.object({
  title: yup
    .string("Masukkan nama judul")
    .min(4, "Minimal 4 karakter")
    .required("Nama judul tidak boleh kosong"),
  content: yup
    .string("Masukkan deskripsi")
    .min(10, "Minimal 10 karakter")
    .required("Deskripsi tidak boleh kosong"),
});

const EditPost = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = useState("");
  const [selectedKategori, setSelectedKategori] = useState("");
  const [kategoriList, setKategoriList] = useState([]);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // const untuk kategori
  const KategoriById = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/kategori/show");
      setKategoriList(data.kategori);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await KategoriById();
      await singlePostById();
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const {
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
    handleBlur,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    setFieldValue,
  } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      title,
      content,
      image: "",
    },

    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    enableReinitialize: true,
    onSubmit: async (values, actions) => {
      updatePost(values);
      actions.resetForm();
    },
  });

  //show post by Id
  const singlePostById = async () => {
    // console.log(id)
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/post/${id}`);
      setTitle(data.post.title);
      setSelectedKategori(data.post.kategoriId);
      setContent(data.post.content);
      setImagePreview(data.post.image.url);
      console.log("single post admin", data.post);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    singlePostById();
  }, []);

  const updatePost = async (values) => {
    try {
      console.log("Selected Kategori:", selectedKategori); // Tambahkan baris ini
      console.log("Update Values:", values);

      values.kategoriId = selectedKategori; // Add the selected category to the values
      const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/update/post/${id}`, values);
      console.log("Update Response:", data);

      if (data.success === true) {
        toast.success("Post updated");
        navigate("/admin/dashboard");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error(error.response.data.error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ bgcolor: "white", padding: "20px 200px" }}>
        <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ pb: 4 }}>
          {" "}
          Ubah Data{" "}
        </Typography>
        <Box component="form" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
          <TextField
            sx={{ mb: 3 }}
            fullWidth
            id="title"
            label="Nama Judul"
            name="title"
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
            placeholder="Nama Judul"
            value={values.title}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            error={touched.title && Boolean(errors.title)}
            helperText={touched.title && errors.title}
          />

          {/* edit kategori */}
          <Select
            sx={{ mb: 3 }}
            fullWidth
            id="kategori"
            label="Pilih Kategori"
            name="kategori"
            placeholder="Pilih Kategori"
            value={selectedKategori}
            onChange={(e) => setSelectedKategori(e.target.value)}
          >
            <MenuItem value="" disabled>
              Pilih Kategori
            </MenuItem>
            {kategoriList.map((kategori) => (
              <MenuItem key={kategori._id} value={kategori._id}>
                {kategori.namakat}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>

          {/* tulis deskripsi */}
          <Box sx={{ mb: 3 }}>
            <ReactQuill
              theme="snow"
              placeholder={"Tulis deskripsi"}
              modules={modules}
              value={values.content}
              onChange={(e) => setFieldValue("content", e)}
            />
            <Box
              component="span"
              sx={{ color: "#d32f2f", fontSize: "12px", pl: 2 }}
            >
              {touched.content && errors.content}
            </Box>
          </Box>

          {/* gambar */}
          <Box border="2px dashed blue" sx={{ p: 1 }}>
            <Dropzone
              acceptedFiles=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"
              multiple={false}
              //maxFiles={3}
              onDrop={(acceptedFiles) =>
                acceptedFiles.map((file, index) => {
                  const reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                  reader.onloadend = () => {
                    setFieldValue("image", reader.result);
                  };
                })
              }
            >
              {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive }) => (
                <Box
                  {...getRootProps()}
                  p="1rem"
                  sx={{
                    "&:hover": { cursor: "pointer" },
                    bgcolor: isDragActive ? "#cceffc" : "#fafafa",
                  }}
                >
                  <input name="image" {...getInputProps()} />
                  {isDragActive ? (
                    <>
                      <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                        <CloudUploadIcon
                          sx={{ color: "primary.main", mr: 2 }}
                        />
                      </p>
                      <p style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: "12px" }}>
                        {" "}
                        Tarik ke sini
                      </p>
                    </>
                  ) : values.image === null ? (
                    <>
                      <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                        <CloudUploadIcon
                          sx={{ color: "primary.main", mr: 2 }}
                        />
                      </p>
                      <p style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: "12px" }}>
                        Tahan dan tarik gambar di sini
                      </p>
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <Box
                        sx={{
                          display: "flex",
                          justifyContent: "space-around",
                          alignItems: "center",
                        }}
                      >
                        <Box>
                          <img
                            style={{ maxWidth: "100px" }}
                            src={
                              values.image === "" ? imagePreview : values.image
                            }
                            alt=""
                          />
                        </Box>
                      </Box>
                    </>
                  )}
                </Box>
              )}
            </Dropzone>
          </Box>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            elevation={0}
            sx={{ mt: 3, p: 1, mb: 2, borderRadius: "25px" }}
            // disabled={loading}
          >
            Simpan Perubahan
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default EditPost;
```

I tried to update it but the AdminDashboard doesn't change.